# How to write xpath using span and class.

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<a class="lightBoxCloseJs buttonize btnDftAct" onclick="if (!doubleClick) { doubleClick = true; confirmDisconnect('Line_0.WL.accessli_w1'); return true; hidepopUP(); return false; } else { return false; };" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span>
Confirm
<span></span>
</span>
</a>
```

There's a button named confirm in the pop-up. I have tried the following xpath `//span[text()='Confirm']`

The following code depecits that I have to click on the confirm button

```
driver.findELement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Confirm']")).click();
```

It is neither clicking on the button nor I'm getting any exception in eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try using this as xpath: "//span[text()='Confirm']/parent::a"
 This will select the parent of your span element (the a element) and click on this instead.

Comment: Why do you have a `<span>` inside the `<span>`  you're looking for? Anyway. the `text()` content of the outer `<span>` is likely not just the word `Confirm`, but the word with leading and trailing whitespace, which is why it doesn't match the XPath predicate. Try joining it all up on one line: `<span>Confirm<span></span></span>`. Remember, the elimination of whitespace is done by the HTML renderer (depending on the CSS `white-space` value), not the XML parser.

Comment: Try to click not on `span`, but on the link `a` that contains `span` tag: `findELement(By.xpath("//a[span[text()='Confirm']]")).click();

Comment: @Kordiko & RemcoW - Tried both of them, it's not working. Problem is that I don't get any NoSuchElementFoundException either.

Comment: Getting the following exception, `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (1173.8333740234375, 111.75). Other element would receive the click: <div style="height: 992px; width: 100%; opacity: 0.6; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); z-index: 999998;" id="lbOverlay" class="lbOverlay"></div>
Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds`

Comment: use the below as cssSelector ;   a[ href='javascript:void(0)']>span

Comment: No luck on that as well, getting the same exception "Element is not clickable at point"

Comment: Your xpath is correct, but there is another html element above the element that you want to click, a kind of overlay with id "lbOverlay". You should hide it before click in the xpath element

Comment: To expand on Andreas’s comment:  Try `"//span[normalize-space()='Confirm']"` to eliminate the newlines.

Comment: Do you have to use XPATH? Have you tried by linktext "Confirm" or by css selector "a.lightBoxCloseJs.buttonize.btnDftAct"?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. It worked.